# How can I add a child element to a specific element in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to add a element to specific view in react native. Thankyou for the answer.

Comment: can you share any piece of code or screenshot that what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

you may add elements in such a way

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Component 1</Text>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
         <Text>Component 2</Text>
       </View>     
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

here is the official link 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/tutorial